# llenar un select con datos de mysql en php

Tags: html

hola chicos espero puedan ayudarme tengo una tabla llamada comuna
con unas columnas de id, comuna, precio.

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar en el select el nombre y el precio de todos los que esten ingresados. pero intento con este codigo y solo me muestra el selec en blanco no se que sucede.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<from>
<select name="comuna" class="form-control">
<?php   
        require 'conexion.php';
        $getcomuna1 = "select * from comuna order by id";
        $getcomuna2 = mysql_query($getcomuna1);

        $while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getcomuna2));
        {   
            $id = $row['id']; 
            $comunas = $row['comuna'];
            $precio = $row['precio'];
        
          ?>
           
         <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $comunas." ".$precio; ?></option>

          <?php 
}; 
?>
</select>
</from>

</body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: Error tipográfico, te sobra `$` en `$while(`

Answer (score 0):

Además de tener algunos errores tipográficos:

- La etiqueta from que supongo será form.
- El $ delante del while)
- El ; al final del while

Tal vez te resulte más cómodo de leer el código estructurado de otra manera:

...

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<form>
  <select name="comuna" class="form-control">
  <?php   
    require 'conexion.php';
    $sql = "select * from comuna order by id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
      $id = $row['id']; 
      $comunas = $row['comuna'];
      $precio = $row['precio'];
           
      echo "<option value='$id'>$comunas $precio</option>";
    }
  ?>
  </select>
</form>

</body>
```